# jquery change css dynamically not refreshing in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

In the following code I am trying to show div before ajax request and after completion I want to hide div.
hide() is working fine but show() is not working.
It works well in Firefox.

```
$("#btnpst").click(function () {
   $('#dvloading').show();
   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: "POST",
       async: false,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (data, st) {
           if (st == "success") {
               $('#dvloading').hide();
           }
       },
       error: function () {
           $('#dvloading').hide();
       }
   });
   } //<
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dvloading" style="width: 480px; height: 320px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
    <image src="../loading_2.gif" style="margin-top: 120px;">
</div>
```

Comment: would you mind posting HTML markup

Comment: how you are sure that `hide` is working? The element itself would ve been rendered right?

Comment: its either showing the `DIV` and closing it very quickly (if the ajax call is not taking much time), OR , the `DIV` itself is not rendered correctly, thus giving the illusion that its hidden..

try to give a breakpoint or `alert()` after show to see if its working..

Comment: If I put alert above hide() I am able to see it. without alert it's not visible. ajax call is taking about 10 sec.

Comment: I've just edited it and found an extra `}`, is this a mistake ?

Comment: @ Sheikh Heera no it's typing mistake.

Comment: what if the ajax call succeeds but `st !=== "success"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are testing is locally and the response is pretty fast.
Why not change this line

```
$('#dvloading').hide();
```

to this

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#dvloading').hide();},5000);
```

to see if thats the case. Also it would be helpful to check if there are no js related errors from the javascript console

Comment: If I say setTimeout(function(){$('#dvloading').hide();},5000); it is showing div after ajax success.

           if (st == "success") {
               $('#dvloading').hide(); alert('success');
           }
I can clearly observe more than 10 sec delay from button click to alert.

Answer (score 0):

> "If I put alert above hide() I am able to see it". "without alert it's not visible. ajax call is taking about 10 sec"

these two statements somehow seem contradictory, if your `DIV` is actually shown and then hidden and the ajax call takes about 10 seconds, it should appear so without the alert box also.. I really doubt whether the ajax call takes about 10 sec..

Here is a fiddle to illustrate your scenario, i have removed the content type attribute from the ajax call and used flickr's json response page. its working fine.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4W8V9/)